# Only the last gameobject is renamed after the loop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I save all my gameobject in a .txt file. When I try to load my map with the textfile, everything works as intended, except for the `gameobject.name`. All the objects are placed at the right position and with the good tag. Here a part of the code.

```
void OnMouseDown(){

    if (GlobalManager.MapName != "") {
        string path = @"c:\Users\Ashes\Desktop\Rebel2\" + GlobalManager.MapName + ".txt";
        if (loadedMap == GlobalManager.MapName) {
            txtMessage2 = "This map is already open";
            StartCoroutine (Message1 ());
        }
        if (!File.Exists (path)) {
            txtMessage2 = "This map name not exist, place object to create the map";
            StartCoroutine (Message1 ());

        }
        if (File.Exists (path)) {
            if (loadedMap != GlobalManager.MapName) {
                {
                    loadedMap = GlobalManager.MapName;
                    GameObject[] Tree = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Tree");

                    foreach (GameObject item in Tree) {
                        Destroy (item);
                    }

                    GameObject[] House = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("House");

                    foreach (GameObject item in House) {
                        Destroy (item);
                    }

                    GameObject[] Road = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Road");

                    foreach (GameObject item in Road) {
                        Destroy (item);
                    }

                    GameObject[] Farm = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Farm");

                    foreach (GameObject item in Farm) {
                        Destroy (item);
                    }

                    GameObject[] Wall = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Wall");

                    foreach (GameObject item in Wall) {
                        Destroy (item);
                    }

                }

                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                        overLoadtxt = s;
                        string[] splitArray = overLoadtxt.Split (' ');
                        loadStr1 = splitArray [0]; 
                        loadStr2 = splitArray [1]; 
                        loadStr3 = splitArray [2]; 
                        loadStr4 = splitArray [3]; 
                        loadStr5 = splitArray [4]; 
                        loadStr6 = splitArray [5]; 



                        if (loadStr2 == "House") {
                            Instantiate (House);
                            if (loadStr6 == "LuxHouse") {
                                House.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = img1;
                            }
                            if (loadStr6 == "House1") {
                                House.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = img2;
                            }
                            if (loadStr6 == "Greentex") {
                                House.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = img3;
                            }

                            House.tag = "House";
                            House.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
                            House.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, float.Parse (loadStr5));
                            House.transform.position = new Vector3 (float.Parse (loadStr3), float.Parse (loadStr4), 0);
                            GlobalManager.intHouseName ++;
                            House.name = loadStr1;
                            Debug.Log (House.name);
                        }

                        if (loadStr2 == "Road") {
                            Instantiate (Road);
                            if (loadStr6 == "dirthroad") {
                                Road.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = img4;
                            }
                            Road.tag = "Road";
                            Road.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0.5f, 0.3f, 0);
                            Road.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, float.Parse (loadStr5));
                            Road.transform.position = new Vector3 (float.Parse (loadStr3), float.Parse (loadStr4), 0);
                            GlobalManager.intRoadName ++;
                            Road.name = loadStr1;
                            Debug.Log (Road.name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `debug.log` shows the right thing, house1,house2,road1,house3... but only the last gameobject.name has the change applied.

I'm clueless about this mechanic.

Comment: anyway, you put duplicated curly brackets on purpose? // if (loadedMap != GlobalManager.MapName) {{ , And I think you have to use House's element, not House itself.

Comment: What is "House"? i.e. What have you declared it as? If it's a GameObject, then what you're essentially doing is replacing the reference to the GameObject in your loop, rather than making new Objects. Same with Road probably. If you can post the entire script, I could probably help you figure it out

Comment: @Venkat at Axiom Studios

Comment: Thank for your reply, the project is far more advanced at this time. House is a "public GameObject House;". I don't reference, i Instantiate a new gameobject for each line in my text file.

Comment: It's an in-game map editor. I drag & drop the gameobjects to create the map and after each drop, a line is saved in the text file like this one,     Farm12 Farm -0.16 -0.89 1 1 0 Farm1 (UnityEngine.Sprite).

Comment: The maps created are beautiful. The save and load function work well. My problem is to keep the gameobject.name saved in the text file. For now, only the last gameobject from the text file keep the name. All others gameobject get the generic name from the gameobject from whom they are instanciated.

Comment: I need the unique name for the function delete after i load a map. I've tried to use the coords to find the line to delete in the text file, but it's not working at 100% of the time.

Comment: When i create a new map, I use the same gameobject.name function to name the gameobjects with an unique name in the hierarchy, when i drag & drop, and it work. It's maybe just impossible with a loop. I don't know?

Comment: I have found the solution by try and error.  I have stored all the name in an public static array[] and used the info with a foreach loop in each gameobject void Start() to rename each gameobject with their saved name.